# Is there a way to make wget handle redirects more intelligently, for example don't follow cross-domain redirects if host spanning is off?

Tags: wget

The way that wget handles redirects seems to be pretty bad

I'm aware that following redirect can be disabled with `--max-redirect=0` but that's not what I want

I've identified a couple scenarios where wget's behavior isn't great:

Scenario 1 -- when a redirect is followed, wget still saves the file under the original name rather than the redirected name

For example, server redirects test1.html to test2.html however wget still saves the file as test1.html:

```
$ wget https://server/test1.html
--2022-06-14 12:32:33--  https://server/test1.html
Resolving server (server)... (IPs)
Connecting to server (server)|(IP)|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 308 Permanent Redirect
Location: https://server/test2.html [following]
--2022-06-14 12:32:33--  https://server/test2.html
Reusing existing connection to [server]:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: 'test1.html'

test1.html                                                          [ <=>                                                                                                                                                 ]       0  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2022-06-14 12:32:33 (0.00 B/s) - 'test1.html' saved [0]
```

Desired outcome:  wget should save the file as test2.html instead

Scenario 2: -- cross domain redirects are followed even when host spanning is not turned on:

server1 redirects test3.html to https://server2/test4.html

```
$ wget https://server1/test3.html
--2022-06-14 12:42:58--  https://server1/test3.html
Resolving server1 (server1)... (IPs)
Connecting to server1 (server1)|(IP)|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 308 Permanent Redirect
Location: https://server2/sitemap.txt [following]
--2022-06-14 12:42:59--  https://server2/sitemap.txt
Resolving server2 (server2)... (IPs)
Connecting to server2 (server2)|(IP).. connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: 'test3.html'

test3.html                                                          [ <=>                                                                                                                                                 ]   1.15K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2022-06-14 12:42:59 (12.4 MB/s) - 'test3.html' saved [1176]
```

Desired outcome:  redirect should not be followed because host spanning option is not turned on

Is there any way to pull this off?

In this case I control the server so I can make changes there if needed, but I've already tried multiple types of redirects and they all seem to be treated the same by wget.